# Older History of commands linux

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, history

I want to check history of commands on my linux server that dates 1month and 4 days old, but the history is showing up to 1 month only (I was late checking it earlier).

I know the ' History ' command and how I can make it bigger in ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile, but making it bigger will not fix this issue but it will fix it for future purposes, is there a way to fix that issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is "*no*". With the Bash shell, the list of commands previously typed is stored in `~/.bash_history`. As you've learned, all you can do is configure its (future) maximum size by setting the `HISTFILESIZE` shell variable.

You can also set `HISTTIMEFORMAT` if you'd like a time-stamp recorded along with each command.